# Deployment issue with Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven

I get this error when i try to run `mvn clean deploy -P PROD`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project mysticpaste: Deployment failed: repository element was
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project mysticp
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.getDeploymentRepository(DeployMojo.java:231)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [deploy section](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html#lifecycle-sect-deploy-phase) of the maven book.

You need to define a `<repositories>` element in your `settings.xml` (not in your `pom.xml`, that's bad) or a `<distributionManagement>` element in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Is there a way to specify distributionManagement in the settings.xml?

Comment: do you have a sample code?

Comment: What's settings.xml?

Comment: How does this answer the question? I have it under distributionManagement, but getting the same error.

Comment: the settings.xml is the maven's settings.xml. you can find in under .m2 folder in your home directory

Answer (score 2):

should it  be like (no space b/w profile and -P switch)

```
 mvn clean deploy -PPROD
```