# repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDep loymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

Tags: java, maven, deployment, pom.xml

I'm having a problem while deploying and here is the error message I get:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ core ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.296 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-26T17:05:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy (default-deploy) on project core: Deployment failed: repository element w
as not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDep
loymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I checked some resources on the internet and none of them worked for my case. I think it's related to my `pom.xml`, so here are its related parts:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                         <source>1.7</source>
                         <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
              <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
              <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
              <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
              <id>Appid</id>
              <name>AppName</name>
              <url>http://IPaddress/nexus/content/repositories/Myapps/</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
```

What's the problem, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You have to define the repository where you want to deploy, [see reference](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-sect-deployment.html#staging-sect-deployment-maven-deploy-plugin)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You should include the repository where you want to deploy in the distribution management section of the `pom.xml`.

Example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...   
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>corp1</id>
      <name>Corporate Repository</name>
      <url>scp://repo/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    ...
</distributionManagement>
...
</project>
```

See [Distribution Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management)

Comment: we can configure exactly this in settings.xml file on the  /.m2 directory?

Answer (score 22):

In your pom.xml you should add distributionManagement configuration to where to deploy.

In the following example I have used **file system as the locations.**

```
<distributionManagement>
       <repository>
         <id>internal.repo</id>
         <name>Internal repo</name>
         <url>file:///home/thara/testesb/in</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
```

you can add another location while deployment by using the following command (but to avoid above error you should have at least 1 repository configured) :

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=internal.repo::default::file:///home/thara/testesb/in
```

Answer (score 18):

The issue is fixed by adding repository url under distributionManagement tab in main pom.xml.

> Jenkin maven goal : clean deploy -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://domain:port/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```