# Skip maven deploy for one module

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, spotify-docker-client

I have a multi-module maven project. Parent pom looks like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <packaging>pom</packaging>   
    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

`common` builds a jar, which is added as dependency in the other modules, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>${module.common.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Modules `a` and `b` are Spring Boot projects having the [spotify docker plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven).

I need to be able to run `mvn deploy` in order to get the spotify plugin push the docker image.

`mvn install` works fine, which builds the docker images. But in order to push them, when I run `mvn deploy`, it throws error for the `common` module:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
>   (default-deploy) on project common: Deployment failed: repository
>   element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
>   element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

Searching for this error, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153024/repository-element-was-not-specified-in-the-pom-inside-distributionmanagement-el?rq=1) suggests adding the repository url in the `distributionManagement` section. But I don't want to deploy `common`. I just want to build it, so it gets injected as dependency in the other modules and deploy those other modules. How can I do that?

I tried to deploy only `a` and `b` using this command, but it gives the same error for `common`:

```
mvn clean \
   -DdockerRegistryHost=123.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test1 \
   --projects a,b \
   --also-make \
   deploy
```

Comment: Do you want to set this module to *never* deploy?

Comment: @chrylis Sure, it's not supposed to be deployed, just added as a dependency.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the `maven-deploy-plugin` to executions=none?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by configuring the `maven-deploy-plugin`.

Try adding the following to your parent pom:

```
<build>
    ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
 </build>
```

or add `-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true` to your command line.

Comment: Thank you. Any reason for specifying a `version` here? If we don't specify it, does it pick up the latest version just like any other dependencies?

Comment: No it does not. Always specify plugin dependencies for repeatability.If you do not specify a plugin version then you will get the one that is associated with the particular version of maven that you are using. Also, I don't believe that "pick up the latest version just like any other dependencies" is a thing either.

Comment: @steve how maven will come to know what artifacts to skip upload?

Comment: @SteveC how can I skip maven deploy for a specific module at runtime using `-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true`

Comment: @RishabPrasad, I don't think you can do it that way. You would need to use a profile to do this.

Comment: Just to understand this right, will this skip deployment for the parent or for all projects?
I would like to skip deployment in the parent pom itself, so that only the modules will be deployed while using `mvn deploy`. It currently errors out in parent due to lack of the distributionManagement option.