# Deploy artifacts into two different remote repositories - Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, remote-repository

Need to deploy a artifacts from two remote repositories based on environment specific. So I tried by using profiles in distribution management in pom.xml

```
   <profiles>
<profile>
    <id>dev-repository</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>devRepo</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
        <id>dev</id>
        <url>https://nexus/dev</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>qa-repository</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!devRepo</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
          <repository>
        <id>qa</id>
        <url>https://nexus/qa</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</profile> 
</profiles>
```

Tried Activating the profiles

**> mvn clean deploy -PdevRepo**

I am getting the following error.

**Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter**

seems like pom can't recognize the distributionMangement tags.

But It's working fine without profiles for single distributionManagement.

Any one please advise on this ?

Reference

[Setting up Maven to allow deployment to different repositories easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340673/setting-up-maven-to-allow-deployment-to-different-repositories-easily)

[Deployment issue with Maven Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538180/deployment-issue-with-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using profiles, I would define a distributionManagement with a url of the form `<url>https://nexus/${target.repo}</url>`

Then you can do something like `mvn clean deploy -Ptarget.repo=dev`.

Comment: Note that this answer might be subject to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6870.

Comment: @Michael-O Thank you for the hint (I did not know that), but AFAIK this does not influence the distributionManagement. I have a distributionManagement property in the settings.xml, and commandline should work the same.